# How to perform subtraction between two Arraylist items in java

Tags: java, arraylist, subtraction

I have two list which have data items of String type.The lists are

```
    List<String> all=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> al2=new ArrayList<String>();
```

The items are added in the lists from Resultset as:-

```
                 all.add((rs.getString(3)));
                 all.add((rs.getString(4)));
                 al2.add((rs.getString(3)));
                 al2.add((rs.getString(4)));
```

There are numerical values in the list,I want to subtract the data items from  list according to the column retrieved from resultset i.e

> Subtract(rs.getString(3) of all,rs.getString(3) of al2)

and display there results.How to achieve this subtraction in lists?

Comment: What is the result of subtracting "cat" and "computer"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ,my resultset has data in following form 3.6755604E-10 and lists holds this type of data.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be storing that as a `String`.

Comment: @MES you can use boxed types. For example `Double` rather than `double`

Comment: yup but when I convert it into double I'm not able to trim the values and I can't use Integer ,therefore I used String

Comment: "trim" values? Do you mean round? for `x` digit rounding of `y` try `Math.round(1e<x>*y)*1e-<x>`

Comment: @k_g when I use Double I get values as **8.836411602430871E-10 ** .now I want them to trim like 8.83E-10

Comment: @MES yes, so round to the 1e-13 place. Much faster than String

Comment: and if you mean in general, just write a program that finds the power base 10 (`Math.log10`) then gets the appropriate power of 10

Comment: when I use Math.round(1e<x>*y)*1e-<x> ,I'm getting error as invalid float literal number at 1e.

Comment: That was intended as a template. Replace the <x> with your number. If you need a variable, use `Math.pow`