# Perform Subtraction on list items in java

Tags: java, list, subtraction

I have two list which holds values from ResultSet. Is there any way through which I can subtract one list from another at specific indexes and display the result in tabular format.
I have list in my code as

```
List<Double> all=new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Double> al2=new ArrayList<Double>();
al2.add(rs.getDouble(10));
al2.add(rs.getDouble(11));
all.add(rs.getDouble(11));
```

I want to do

```
al2 at rs.getDouble(11) - all at rs.getDouble(11)
```

Subtraction between two lists at particular column values.How to do this??

Comment: Why are you [double posting this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358778/how-to-perform-subtraction-between-two-arraylist-items-in-java)?

Comment: sorry,will not happen again.Was trying something else with double values,by mistake posted here.But I'm not getting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am bit unclear at what you want, but I am thinking you want to substract all List elements  at specific indexes :-

```
List<Double> all=new ArrayList<Double>();
List<Double> al2=new ArrayList<Double>();
al2.add(rs.getDouble(10));
al2.add(rs.getDouble(11));
all.add(rs.getDouble(11));

for(int i=0;i<all.size()&&i<al2.size();i++){
    double x=al2.get(i);
    double y=all.get(i);
    double z=0;
    if(x>y){ //check to avoid negative subtractions result
        z=x-y;
    }
    else{
    z=y-x;
    }
    System.out.println(z); // do something with the result i am just printing it out
 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot,but how to display it in tabular format through jsp. I did like this<table width = "300px" border = "1" cellspacing="2">

 <c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.diff()}">
   <tr>
   <td>  ${row}  </td>
   </tr>  
   </c:forEach>
 </table>
But ** Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;** Error occurs.

Comment: You're welcome, I think you need to ask a new question for this, specify more details for what errors are you getting. What is `ref.diff()` ? etc. Also to display `$row` use `<c:out value="${row}"/>`

Comment: ref.diff() is the method where difference between two list is calculated and when I use <c:out value="${row}"/> then only last value of z is being displayed.I want the the values to be displayed in tabular format.

Comment: You are doing it wrong , call the `ref.diff()` separately, make it retun array of z i.e `Double[]`. Now use that array in `<c:forEach items` then your `<c:out` should display all values